# Why i += i + i++ equals 0?

Tags: javascript, increment

Consider this code:

```
var i = 0;
>> undefined

i += i + i++;
>> 0

i
>> 0  // why not 1?
```

I would expect `i` to be `1` because of the increment (`++`) operator. What I think should happen is something like:

```
i = 0 + 0 + (i = i + 1)
i = 0 + 1
i = 1
```

Why it's returning zero instead? Could someone explain what happens under the scene?

Comment: The result of the first i++ is 0 (return-and-increment vs increment-and-return (++i))

Comment: Post-increment vs pre-increment

Comment: Note that this is undefined behaviour in C and C++. You can probably unpick in javascript though.

Comment: You have to pre-increment `i += i + ++i;` it works :)

Comment: People shouldn't write code like this.  Strive for clarity.

Comment: `i += i + i++` will be `i = 0 + 0`, hence i remains 0 (since i++ is post-increment)

Comment: Everyone here is focusing on the `i++` part, but the `+=` part is also interesting. It's important to note that the value of the left hand side in `i += i + i++` (which is `i`) is evaluated **before** the right hand side (`i + i++`). And at that moment, `i` is still `0`. So the evaluation really is `i = 0 + 0 + 0`. See http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.2

Comment: @Bathsheba postfix operators have higher precedence than arithmetic operators in javascript. So if `i` was accessed only when used for each operator then the answer should be 1. So it seems like this behaviour is also undefined for javascript. So yeah, never access a variable on the right hand side more than once if you are modifying it.

Comment: @Dunes: I think it's well defined in JS (or maybe I missed your point). After `i++`, `i` will have the value `(i + 1)`, but the result of the expression is `i`. If you access `i` after you did `i++`, you get the new value. Examples: `var i = 0; console.log(i + i++); i = 0; console.log(i++ + i);`.

Comment: @FelixKling That's not how postfix ++ works. postfix ++ increments a variable and then returns the *original* value. So when `i` starts as `0`, the expression `i + i++` goes to `i + 0` -> `1 + 0` -> `1`. But you make a very good point about when in the expression that the left hand `i` should be evaluated.

Comment: @Dunes: I'm pretty sure addition first evaluates the lhs and then the rhs. So `i + i++` -> `0 + i++` -> `0 + 0`. http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1 . This has nothing to do with precedence btw. Precedence just means that the expression is evaluated as `i + (i++)` and not as `(i + i)++` (which would be an error anyway).

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you are right. Just checked, the standard is very explicitly left to right. Also, hadn't realised you were linking to the appropriate part of the standard in your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to realize is that `i++` increments `i`, but returns the *original* value of `i`. 
This postfix version of the operator (also called post-increment) is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_(.2B.2B)):

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.

So this evaluates to:

```
i = 0 + (j = i, i += 1, j);
```

<sup>Note the use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) above.</sup>

What you're describing is much more like the prefix version of the operator (also called pre-increment), `++i`, which would evaluate to:

```
i = 0 + (i += 1);
```

And which does indeed return 1.

Comment: Note that if you use `++i` instead, you do indeed get 1.

Comment: Or if the order is changed: `i++ + i`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
i += i + (++i);
```

If you use i++ the increment is **after** the expression, so it will resolve simply as *i*